# Failed to retrieve Firebase Instance Id (No firebase service is working)

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I ran into a problem while adding Firebase services into my app using android studio
here is the logcat:

> 2021-08-09 12:17:24.764 6480-6480/com.nanosoft.fawwalet
> D/ActivityThread: ActivityThread::handleMakeApplication()
> data=AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{13e94c8
> com.nanosoft.fawwalet}} appContext=android.app.ContextImpl@3aa7961
> appContext.mOpPackageName=com.nanosoft.fawwalet
> appContext.mBasePackageName=com.nanosoft.fawwalet
> appContext.mPackageInfo=android.app.LoadedApk@2976c86
> data.restrictedBackupMode= false data.providers=
> [ContentProviderInfo{name=com.nanosoft.fawwalet.mobileadsinitprovider
> className=com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider},
> ContentProviderInfo{name=com.nanosoft.fawwalet.firebaseinitprovider
> className=com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider},
> ContentProviderInfo{name=com.nanosoft.fawwalet.workmanager-init
> className=androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer},
> ContentProviderInfo{name=com.nanosoft.fawwalet.lifecycle-process
> className=androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer},
> ContentProviderInfo{name=com.nanosoft.fawwalet
> className=com.nanosoft.fawwalet.data.PlaceDetailProvider}]
> Caller=android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication:7446
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500:301
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage:2148
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:106 android.os.Looper.loop:246
> 2021-08-09 12:17:24.946 6480-6480/com.nanosoft.fawwalet I/FirebaseApp:
> Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
> 2021-08-09 12:17:25.161 6480-6480/com.nanosoft.fawwalet
> I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
> 2021-08-09 12:17:25.583 6480-10717/com.nanosoft.fawwalet W/FA: Failed to retrieve Firebase Instance Id

Any help will be appreciated

here is my manifiest file

```
 <service android:name=".utils.PushNotificationService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I followed Firebase tutorials to establish my FCM but still no luck

heres the java class

```
    public class PushNotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "PushNotification";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // ...

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.

            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds

            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code using which you are expecting the Firebase Instance ID.

Comment: I am just preparing for my app for FCM

Comment: So have you written code to get the Firebase Instance Id?

Comment: No sir the only code I will supply the only code I write to the matter
I don't recall asking for the ID but the FCM not working at all 
thank you for your time

Comment: In the `PushNotificationService` have you overrided the method `onNewToken`? this will give you the new token whenever the token is updated.

Comment: i've altered the PushNotifcationService as told

Comment: So now you have the new token ..... you can use it. If its' working then mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

In the PushNotificationService you need to override the method `onNewToken` this will give you the new token whenever the token is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by doing the following:

1. downgrading google play services to
   'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8' was 4.3.9

2.using mavenCentral()

3. raising minSdkVersion 18 was 16

I figured that myself while trying to reproduce the problem so it has nothing to do with Fire Base instance Id since I did not call it.
Firebase services are up and running